# Setting System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Calibri") doesn't work on other PCs

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

For a WPF application where I need to display numbers in scientific notation (eg., 10² 10ⁿ), I've used code like below. I'm assigning these "Run" variables to a TextBlock, I have to do this from code-behind file in a Converter and hence this C# code and I cannot use XAML.

The issue that I'm noticing is that on my development machine it works fine, displays as expected like 10², whereas in others' machines, I see this as 102, instead of superscript.

Can anyone please let me know how to troubleshoot this or what I'm missing?

Btw, the reason I'm setting the FontFamily specifically is apparently I found out that not all font families support superscripts.

```
        Run logBase = new Run();
        logBase.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Calibri");
        logBase.Text = "10";

        Run logExp = new Run();
        logExp.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Calibri");
        logExp.Text = "2";
        logExp.Typography.Variants = FontVariants.Superscript;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the specs of the other machines? What's different about them? Are they on XP? Calibri was first distributed with Vista, so XP machines won't have it by default. Try a different font and see if you have the same issue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri

Comment: The other machines that I was referring to are all developer machines and all of them are configured exactly in the same way. Windows 7, VS 2012.